# Place a select input in different position inside a phrase

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am building a Ruby on Rails app, I have a model Lesson which contains many Questions and each Question has many choices

```
class Lesson < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :Questions
end

class Question < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :choices
  belongs_to :lesson
end

class Choice < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :question
end
```

Each question is different than others in the form, I mean sometimes the select option (of the choices) will be in the beginning, sometimes in the middle, sometimes elsewhere in the sentence :

I **--- a select input here ---**  (hear) a new song on the radio.

I went to the cinema yesterday. The film  **--- a select input here ---** (begin) late.

How I can model that dynamically ?

Answer (score 0):

You an already answered on your question. Just use special marker inside question (like your `--- a select input here ---`) to specify position of input field in your question. Then just replace marker to input in view.